# Using Flextable outside of GWT

Tags: java

I use FlexTables extensively in my GWT applications. I have recently returned to vanilla Java in eclipse (AWT etc) and find myself doing GUI work again. What is the closest equivalent to a FlexTable? I'd love to never touch FlexLayouts that I used to use ever again!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use Java's JTable for any table-based graphics.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: GWT's FlexTable feels much more extensible. http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~FlexTable

It allows you to create a JPanel, then immediately add the FlexTable as the only child. You can then add n elements to the FlexTable programmatically, by calling addWidget(row, cell, element). I'd really like to find a genuine equivalent in Java SE 6.